# Как добавить элемент в кортеж на 0 индекс в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, tuple

У меня есть кортеж:

```
pp = 'category', 'key:2', 'title:hr'
```

И необходимо добавить элемент в кортеж на 0 индекс, чтобы остальные просто сдвинулись дальше. К примеру у меня есть переменная `symbol = '$'`

После вывода кортежа я должен получить:

```
'$', 'category', 'key:2', 'title:hr'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кортеж является *неизменяемым* объектом, поэтому Вы *не можете* добавить в него новый элемент.

Но Вы можете создать новый кортеж на основе имеющегося. Для удобства можно преобразовать его в список, воспользоваться методом [`insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) и преобразовать обратно.

***Пример:***

```py
pp = 'category', 'key:2', 'title:hr'
symbol = '$'

pp = list(pp)
pp.insert(0, symbol)
pp = tuple(pp)
print(pp)
```

***stdout:***

```py
('$', 'category', 'key:2', 'title:hr')
```

Comment: Много движений... `pp = '$', *pp`

Comment: @user207200 можно рассматривать в качестве ответа, только добавьте немного информации к ответу :)

Comment: или так  `pp = tuple(symbol) + pp`

Comment: @MaximChyorny ответ на ваш вопрос один - кортеж неизменяемая структура данных.

Comment: @user207200, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @SergFSM, тоже.